# How to manage Oauth 2.0 redirect on emulator

Tags: android, ionic-framework, redirect, oauth-2.0, android-emulator

I'm working on a project which is a mobile application developed with Ionic. The project is split into two parts: a mobile front-end and a back-end. The back-end is performing all the calls to external services and applying business rules, while the front-end only calls my back-end.

One of the services I'm using is a IAM service using Oauth2 protocol. I've implemented the authorization code flow to integrate this service. Until now, I was always using the command `ionic serve` to run my front-end in a web browser, and everything is going well.

But now, for testing purposes, I need to run my front-end in an android emulator. In order for my front-end to contact my back-end, I'm using the IP `10.0.2.2` (which is the alias of the loopback of my machine where my back-end is running).

The problem is with the redirect of the authentication service. It is not something that I have control on, and it can take weeks or months for the service provider to update my client configuration. When I want to authenticate myself through the app running on emulator, it opens a `InAppBrowser` to perform the authentication. When I successfully authenticated myself against the service, the redirect URI is `http://127.0.0.1:8080/xxxx`, and this response is sent to that `InAppBrowser`.

My question is:
Is there a way to replace the base URL of that response (without changing the client configuration), so that I can send the call response to my back-end ?

**NOTE**: I've been trying to find a solution online, but I can't find anything on that topic. I suspect that in that matter, I probably lack some vocabulary in order to find what I'm looking for.
Is there a way to

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks for the suggestion. After reading the thread and linked questions, it doesn't seem to help for my problem.

Comment: Suggestion: look at these links: [Ionic forum: OAuth what would the Redirect URL be](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/oauth-what-would-the-redirect-url-be/117165/3), or [Stack Overflow: Failing to retrieve OAuth 2.0 access token on android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732242/)