# GoogleAccountCredential setSelectedAccountName but still null

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-authentication, google-oauth, google-account

The account name is null even after being set.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085685/googleaccountcredential-name-is-null-despite-calling-setselectedaccountname-and), but I do have the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission in both the manifest and secured at runtime.

The following setup is being run on a Pixel XL emulator API 25 (Android 7.1.1).

#### Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

#### Activity

```
private void queryAPI() {
    if (mCredential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, RCP_AUTH_CRED);
            return;
        }

        mCredential.setSelectedAccountName("test@gmail.com");
        Log.d(TAG, "queryAPI: account name " + mCredential.getSelectedAccountName());
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RCP_AUTH_CRED:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                queryAPI();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: " + Integer.toString(grantResults[0]));
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

#### Logcat

```
04-18 21:26:47.590 2700-2700/com.package D/MainActivity: queryAPI: account name null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this google account "test@gmail.com" setup in accounts on the device?

First you need to setup the google account that you want to use it in your app by going to settings / accounts / add account on the device where you are testing it. Just passing account name is not enough, the account must exist on the device.

If google account is required in order for users to use your app, you can just force users to create google account by directing users to account selection screen by firing an intent using newChooseAccountIntent() method.

Comment: Is that a necessary precondition? Didn't see that in the docs anywhere.

Comment: it relies on accounts right, did you test it with created account?

Comment: Was trying to avoid this because I haven't been able to pair an emulated phone with the emulated wearable I'm testing.

Comment: Hmmm, looks like the account must be on the device... If you update the answer to make that explicit, I will accept it!

Comment: I have used this method to login, How to log out using GoogleAccountCredential?

Answer (score 4):

Use setSelectedAccount() instead of setSelectedAccountName().

```
 mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());

        // to set accountName manually instead of prompting user to select it
        mCredential.setSelectedAccount(new Account("xyz@gmail.com", "com.android.example"));
```

Give your gmail account as the first parameter and your package name as the second.